# How to fix an a concatenate formula conditional to a non blank cell

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula, concatenation, is-empty

I'm trying to concatenate cells from columns C, D & E as long as Cell A is not blank (has a value)

Cell A is a formula based on listing weekdays:

```
=IF(WORKDAY(A$28-1;ROW(21:21))>A$29;"";WORKDAY(A$28-1;ROW(21:21)))
```

My concatenate formula is as follows:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A24);"";CONCATENATE(E24;CHAR(10);D24;CHAR(10);C24))
```

The formula is still concatenating even if Cell A is blank

[snapshot of excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aIZg.jpg)

Comment: I see you've asked a total of 8 questions over the last several months yet never once accepted any response as an answer. That may be something you should correct if you expect volunteers to support your future inquiries. This especially so when you use an unattributed formula from one of the responses you received but failed to acknowledge.

Comment: sorry im stil learning how to use stackoverflow.com . i just realized there is an accept button next to an answer!

Comment: Thanks for being a good community member, Lou.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Blank

**Blank** (**Empty Cell**) means 'nothing' inside the cell, no formula no value i.e. a cell containing an **Empty String** ("") is **not** blank. As soon as you have put a **formula** or **any value** into a cell, it isn't blank anymore.

You should use this formula:

```
=IF(A24="";"";CONCATENATE(E24;CHAR(10);D24;CHAR(10);C24))
```

where `A24=""` **includes** blank cells, so you don't have to use `ISBLANK`, too.

Comment: fwiw, COUNTBLANK works on zero length strings but ISBLANK does not.

Comment: oh your the hero i needed!